# shell: remote echo hostname and write it locally

Tags: shell, ssh, echo

Part 1) I try to execute an `echo hostname` on my remote host (using ssh).
just the `hostname`command it works. But I have to echo the hostname because I have to copy it.

Part2) Paste the copied hostname (of the host) to a folder which is local. Can someone help me? I tried:

```
ssh -tt -i key.pem centos@ec2xxx .amazonaws.com sudo sh -c \ "echo `hostname`" >> /myfile
```

But this is just giving me an empty line.
I have to use echo in it (assignement)

Comment: Try removing the `-tt` option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
ssh -tt -i key.pem centos@ec2xxx.amazonaws.com 'sudo sh -c "echo `hostname`"' >> /file
```

Answer (score 0):

You're jumping through unnecessary hoops.  You can simply run `hostname` as the remote command, and redirect ssh's stdout:

```
ssh "$host" hostname >>/file
```

For example:

```
$ rm -f /tmp/hn; ssh "$host" hostname >/tmp/hn; wc -c /tmp/hn
6 /tmp/hn
```

(that's a 5-char hostname in there, redacted!)

Comment: I needed to use echo. (It was for an school assignment with using echo). But your answel will be the best without echo. thanks