# shell script to search for hosts on the storage array

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm working on my shell script, that searches for the name of a host in all of our storage array (3par). My script (1) connects to all of the devices (2) run a command to resolve the hostname and (3) redirect its output to a file.

My problem is:

1. I don't know how to output the hostname on the screen and
2. I can't let the script tell me, on which machine the host runs on.

Here's my incomplete and not so good script. :)

```
#!/bin/bash
green=`tput setaf 2`
nc=`tput sgr0`
>/home/3par/tmp

read -p "Enter the host: " hostname

for ip in `cat /home/3par/pds |awk '{print $2}'`
do
ssh usadmin@$ip -i ~/.ssh/us3par_rsa 'showhost -d' >/home/3par/out
echo "$ip `cat /home/3par/out`" >>/home/3par/tmp
```

The pds text file contains:

```
us3par1 192.168.3.20
us3par2 192.168.3.21
us3par3 192.168.3.22
```

The output that I want should be:
[If host is found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVnnm.png)

BTW, I'm just a beginner on scripting so I would really appreciate any help, comment, and suggestion. :)

Comment: Reading a shell scripting tutorial might be more useful than asking here.

Comment: What's the use of this portal if no one can ask.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, then the following adjustment should solve your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the host: " hostname
while IFS=' ' read -r -a ip
do
  foundhost="$(ssh usadmin@${ip[1]} -i ~/.ssh/us3par_rsa hostname 2> /dev/null)"
  if [ "$hostname" = "$foundhost" ]
  then
    echo "This host $hostname is on ${ip[0]}" | tee -a /home/3par/out
  fi
done < pds
```

- Assumption: pds is a (multi line) text file with two columns, that are seperated by a white space character.
- Your wanted output *"This host us4c11j8a4 is on us3par2"* will be redirected to `/home/3par/out` (in case the entered hostname can be found).

This could also be helpful:

- [shell: remote echo hostname and write it locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085580/shell-remote-echo-hostname-and-write-it-locally)
- [How to fetch a hostname of a remote instance using bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713178/how-to-fetch-a-hostname-of-a-remote-instance-using-bash-script)

Comment: Thanks Rene. Very much appreciated your response. Actually the objective is: 1.) Once it connects to multiply array it will run a command "showhost -d" and redirect it to a file. 2.) searches the hostname on the redirected file and output it on the screen if found.

Comment: **First**: is it important to explicitly call `showhost -d`? Is `hostname` (retrieving the host name of the remote host in this scenario) not an option? **Second**: the output should be both, (1) written to a file and (2) printed on the screen, if the hostname matches the entered one?

Comment: is it important to explicitly call showhost -d? Yes, because there's no other command that will list all connected hosts on the array. Is hostname (retrieving the host name of the remote host in this scenario) not an option? Not, an option. The remote host is not a unix box, instead it's a 3par storage array which has it's own commands available Second: the output should be both, (1) written to a file and (2) printed on the screen, if the hostname matches the entered one? Not really required to write it to a file but what's important is to print it on the screen once found.